# personalize a password protected page on Salient (Wordpress theme)

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming, background-image

I'm trying to personalize my portfolio homepage, which is password protected and has been built in Wordpress with the Salient theme (http://federicaaradelli.com/).

I've only managed to add some margins and paddings to the password-form but I can't change the page background color or add a background image.

That's what I've written in the personalized CSS:

```
.post-password-form {
margin-top: 20%;
}

.post-password-form {
padding:10px;
background-color: white;
}
```

I've also tried to inspect the page/elements but it didn't really get me anywhere.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks!
Federica

Comment: You should post both html and css to get a help. Generally, it should be something like `body { background-color: yellow; }`

Comment: The code is too long to do copy/paste but you can check it inspecting the page. The section starts with `<div class="container-wrap" style="opacity: 1; margin-bottom: 211px; min-height: 378px;">`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.container-wrap {
    background-color: yellow !important; /* Generally, you don't need 
                                            to use "!important" in
                                            your CSS, but currently
                                            there is some overwriting
                                            in your code and I use
                                            "!important" as a quick
                                            fix.
                                         */
    background-image: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);
    /* Optionally: */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%; /* Sometimes it would be better to
                              use "cover" instead of "100%",
                              but in your case "100%" is the
                              best option.
                           */                                    
}
```

Comment: Done! The `.container-wrap`, tho, changed the background to all the pages on the website so I had to remove it!